# What is wrong with creating a React Native app this way?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to create a basic React Native app. While I can create the project, it will not run inside the simulator.

After the app loads, it immediately quits. If I remove `node_modules` and do `npm install` to download all the modules fresh, I will see the app reload the Javascript. Then when it hits 100%, it immediately quits again.

The steps I used to create the app are as follows:

```
$ react-native init demo1
$ cd demo1
$ react-native run-ios
```

That's literally it. I'm using the following versions of tools:

```
$ node --version
v6.11.2
$ npm --version
3.10.10
$ react-native --version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.48.0
```

The full log is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a3e63c0941eef20dcca815da5b3809ec). What am I doing wrong?

---

Investigating this more, it turns out the Xcode project fails with a stack trace:

```
2017-09-02 13:03:00.775 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:188] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x6080001a2ae0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6000000a1f80>, executor: (null))
2017-09-02 13:03:00.804 [warn][tid:main][RCTBridge.m:114] Class RCTCxxModule was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?
2017-09-02 13:03:00.825 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:301] Running application r1 ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2017-09-02 13:03:00.960 r1[47802:5600672] -[NSTaggedPointerString unsignedIntValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa313434323930327
2017-09-02 13:03:00.977 r1[47802:5600672] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString unsignedIntValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa313434323930327'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e094b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010cf4a141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e104134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e01b840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e01b3b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   r1                                  0x000000010c301394 -[RCTMultipartStreamReader emitProgress:contentLength:final:callback:] + 244
    6   r1                                  0x000000010c301b8a -[RCTMultipartStreamReader readAllPartsWithCompletionCallback:progressCallback:] + 1610
    7   r1                                  0x000000010c3514bc -[RCTMultipartDataTask URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:] + 444
    8   CFNetwork                           0x000000010daf4c51 __88-[NSURLSession delegate_streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 51
    9   Foundation                          0x000000010ca543b7 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
    10  Foundation                          0x000000010ca540bb -[NSBlockOperation main] + 101
    11  Foundation                          0x000000010ca52877 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 627
    12  Foundation                          0x000000010ca4e5fc __NSOQSchedule_f + 198
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111d7605c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111d5494f _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 221
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111d55669 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1084
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111d57ec4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 634
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111d57bef _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011210d5a2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011210d07d start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Is this some sort of bug or is this something I did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a 0.48 issue. Try using 0.47.1 and you should be fine.

```
react-native init demo1 --version react-native@0.47.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in RN 0.48.1. If you create a new project (as of September 4, 2017) you shouldn't run into this issue.